# Apparent discrepancy in length of a string of unicode characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am compressing [this string](https://pastebin.com/WyunCpPs) (pbn_text) in javascript using LZString
and I am having problems decompressing in python (I am reading the string from a file)

```
    <form id="fileInputForm">
        <label for="file-upload">Upload file</label>
        <input type="file" id="file-upload" accept=".pbn" on:change={readFile}>
        <label for="file-description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="file-description" placeholder="File description">
    </form>

<script>
async function readFile(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file == null)
        return; // If user cancels file selection

    pbn_text = await file.text();
    file_name = await file.name;
}
</script>
```

My script for the compression is

```
    var compressed = LZString.compress(pbn_text);
    const codePoints = Array.from(compressed)
    .map((v) => v.codePointAt(0).toString(16))
    .map((hex) => "\\u{" + hex + "}");
    console.log(compressed.length);
    console.log(codePoints.length);
```

I have mapped the compressed string to its unicode codepoints, and there is a discrepancy in the lengths:

compressed = 1020

codePoints = 1019

Where does this arise?

Comment: How are you assigning the string to your `pbn_text` variable? Are you reading it from a file, AJAX result, textarea, etc? Also, which version of lz-string are you using? The reason I'm asking - I tried replicating your issue with lz-string 1.5.0. The length was identical. You can see the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3rzu50hv/). Please note that I was working with the string as it was in pastebin.com. Your original string might be different, and something might be lost when you post it to pastebin.com .

Comment: I am reading it from file (question amended). The text file and the pastebin string look alike (304 lines with an empty line at the end) The pastebin string is copied and pasted from the text file - lz-string@1.5.0

Comment: Your fiddle gives a different length 997. why?

Comment: Do you get the length of 997 when c/p from your file, or with the pastebin.com string (or both)?

Comment: I get 997 from paste bin and if I paste in the file contents. Is the problem reading from file? I've put my code in the question

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rzu50hv/1/) based on your edited code. I can replicate the results you get (1020 vs 1019). The same thing happens if I use `FileReader` ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3rzu50hv/2/)). I was wondering why this was happening, so I deleted the second half of your pbn file (the length matched). Then I restored the file as it was, and removed the last quarter (length matched), last 10 lines (still matching), etc. Eventually, I discovered that the first character in the line 303 was what's causing the discrepancy (replaced S with N, length matched).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255084/discussion-between-fiddlingaway-and-psionman).